# Is there C++ code that takes infinite time to compile?

Tags: computability, compilers, semi-decidability

Is C++ as a formal language recursively enumerable? If yes, is there any invalid C++ code that takes "infinite" time to compile?

Comment: In fact, C++ template language is Turing complete. Why "invalid" C++? Even valid C++ can take an infinite time to compile (in theory).

Comment: Enumerability and compilation time are not as closely related as you might think: compilation involves more than parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory this code should compile infinitely

```
template<long long K>
struct t {
  enum { value = (K&1) ? t<K+1>::value : t<K-1>::value};
};
int main() {
  int i = t<1>::value;
}
```

But in real life compilers are limiting template instantiation depth.
Another thing is that long long is limited so you cannot represent all integers.

Comment: I was under the impression that the standards specify minimums on such (just like length of names), so a compiler that supports greater than minimum depth might *almost* be considered to be extending the language as a programmer can only rely on the minimum depth being implemented without implementation-specific knowledge. (Even that is theory since a compiler might falsely claim compliance with a standard.)

Comment: Note: instead of using `long long` you could encode Peano Numbers in the type system.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton: The C++ Standard specifies recommended minima and the C++ compilers usually provide flags to adjust the default limits they implement.